# if city name is same for unique ID in two dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to check if city name is same for all ID in df and df2 . if city name is different then mutate new column different city name and show as "different name"

I have many columns in data frame and i want to mutate df and want to check if id is present in df and df2 then check if city is same so if city is not same then mutate df as "different city".

its working but this is changing column names as id1, city2 etc. i want to keep my df as it is but only want to mutate with diff_city column.

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2251","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2923","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal","singh,nkunj","garg","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))

df1 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","DEL","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","del","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))


dfj <- full_join(df, df1, by = "ID", suffix = c("1", "2"), keep = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(same_city = (city1 == city2) %>% replace_na(FALSE))
```

the output should be like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with the help of `match` -

```
df$diff_city <- ''
df$diff_city[df$city != df1$city[match(df$ID, df1$ID)]] <- 'Different city'
df

#        ID city           Name      diff_city
#1  DEV2962  DEL      dev,akash               
#2  KTN2251  mum    singh,rahul               
#3  ANA2719  DEL   abbas,salman               
#4  ITI2624  MUM            lal Different city
#5  DEV2698  DEL    singh,nkunj               
#6  HRT2923  del           garg               
#7           MUM       ali,sanu               
#8  KTN2624  DEL    singh,kunal               
#9  ANA2548  del   tomar,lakhan               
#10 ITI2535  MUM thakur,praveen Different city
#11 DEV2732  mum     ali,sarman               
#12 HRT2837  mum     khan,zuber               
#13 ERV2951  mum  singh,giriraj               
#14 KTN2542  mum  sharma,lokesh               
#15 ANA2813  DEL    pawar,pooja               
#16 ITI2210  DEL  sharma,nikita
```